# elsif statement not working in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm new to learning ruby and I was wondering why when I input 150 it does not say your perfect. Here is the code im working on.

```
 def prompt     
   print ">> " 
 end  

 puts "welcome to the weight-calc 3000! Enter you weight below!"  

 prompt; weight = Integer(gets.chomp())  

 if weight > 100 && weight < 300     
   puts "your healthy!" 
 elsif weight > 300     
   puts "your fat" 
 elsif weight < 100  
   puts "your skinny"  
 elsif weight == 150     
   puts "your perfect" 
 end
```

Comment: If statements are exclusive. Only the first branch found who's condition is true is executed. Else if is different then also if. Robby doesn't have any sort of also if built in, but it could be added.

Answer (score 7):

The condition `if weight > 100 && weight < 300` is `true` for the value `150`, so the last `elsif` isn't even entered.

You should put more specific conditions (`weight == 150`) before generic conditions (`weight > 100 && weight < 300`).

Answer (score 2):

Look at your first condition:

```
if weight > 100 && weight < 300
```

When `weight` is `150`, it is `> 100` and `< 300`, so the first condition is true.

Move `if weight == 150` to the top of the chain.